# Meaning of $ e^x = 1 + x + \Theta(x^2)$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

In the CLRS book chapter 3: When $x → 0$, the approximation of $e^x$ by $1+x$ is quite good:

**$$e^x = 1 + x + \Theta(x^2)$$**

How is it to be interpreted, what is the role of asymptotic notation here? If I interpret the $\Theta$ naively as standard big-$O$ notation then this statement surely makes no sense?!

Comment: Wikipedia has an explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics

Comment: @dantopa: Don't anyhow edit notation that you don't understand! Look up Landau notation.

Comment: By the way, none of the answers have pointed out that it makes no sense for you to say that if you interpret the $Θ$ as standard big-O notation then the statement make no sense. In fact, **using standard big-O notation**, $e^x ∈ 1+x+O(x^2)$ **as $x → 0$**. Note that the limiting condition was explicitly stated in your book. Your book chose to use "$Θ$" because it's true and stronger than "$O$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could understand why this might be confusing and, indeed, it was when I first saw it as well. The trick is that one is probably used to "big-O" ("big-$\Omega$", "big-$\Theta$", etc.) notations as being used in phrases like "this algorithm is $O(n^2)$" and so forth which suggest that big-O describes a *property* of some particular object of interest, yet here it is being used as a *quantity* in and of itself.

However, there is no mystery to this: If you use a big-$O$ (etc.) like it's a quantity, i.e. as you give

$$1 + x + \Theta(x^2)$$

that means that it is effectively a placeholder for *an unspecified function that has the indicated asymptotic behavior*. In the case you give, the unspecified function is the remainder of the exponential series - the function that must be substituted in order to make the equality hold exactly. The notation tells you the behavior of that remainder as you vary $x$, and thus how the error in approximating $e^x$ by $1 + x$, varies as well. It is also important to note that big-Os have a "direction" associated with them, much like a limit: in the phrase related to the running time of a computer algorithm, the asymptotic is taken as $n$ goes to positive infinity. Here, it is (usually!) taken as $x$ goes to *zero*. This may be notated with something like

$$e^x = 1 + x + \Theta(x^2),\ \ \ \ \ \ x \rightarrow 0$$

but it also may not be if this is simply implied by context: in this case we pretty much know a Taylor polynomial is bad once you're suitably far out from its point of expansion, so what we'd really like to know is how *good* it gets, i.e. how much the error *shrinks*, when you get suitably *close to* the point of expansion, since that can tell you both if you're close enough to hit a desired level of accuracy and/or if you need to go closer.

Answer (score 4):

The role of the asymptotic notation here is the same as the role of most asymptotic notation anywhere: To tell you how large the error is. In this case, using $\Theta$, the term tells you that the error is roughly proportional to $x^2$ (for small $x$).

There is, of course, a rigorous definition of what "roughly proportional" means in this case. It means that as long as $|x|<K$ for some bound $K$, there are two real constants $0<c<C$ such that the (absolute value of the) error of your approximation is between $cx^2$ and $Cx^2$.